# 'high blood pressure' vs 'a high blood pressure'

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

What is the difference between these two sentences:

> I have high blood pressure.

and

> I have **a** high blood pressure.

I can only guess that the first one mean that I have high blood pressure all the time. Meanwhile, the second one mean that I measured blood pressure a couple of times and one of those times the blood pressure was high. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

> **I have high blood pressure**

Is correct.

> I have a high blood pressure

Is not correct.

We do not use the phrase “a pressure“, unless (1) you are talking about a specific pressure at a specific location,

> I feel a strange pressure in my belly.
>
> The air pressure gauge shows a pressure of 30 psi.

Or (2) you are using the article “a“ to introduce something.

> I feel a pressure to conform.
>
> I feel a growing pressure to conform.

(Compare:)

> I feel pressured to succeed.

You can say:

> I have a high blood pressure **level**.

This is all right, because you’re saying “a level”, not “a pressure.”  This is like saying:

> I have a high level of blood pressure.

If you mean to say you have a specific reading which is unusual, you can say:

> I have a high level of blood pressure right now.

Or

> My blood pressure is high (right now).
>
> My blood pressure is higher than usual.